# How to implement label of contact of contact list using php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, iphone, json, contacts

I am working on iPhone API in which i have to return contact of contact. If we select main_id = 1, then we check contact list of user=1 and return his contact list in label 0, then contact list of users who are in label 0, return them in next label 1 and so on..

{

```
"message": {
    "label0": [
        {
            "user_id": "2",
            "name": "Parminder",
            "phone": "+919501288502"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "5",
            "name": "Amit",
            "phone": "+919501288505"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "3",
            "name": "Deepak",
            "phone": "+919501288503"
        }
    ],
    "label1": [
        {
            "user_id": "4",
            "name": "Prince",
            "phone": "+919501288504"
        }
    ],
    "label2": [
        {
            "user_id": "6",
            "name": "Kamal",
            "phone": "+919501288506"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Please help me to make this script.Thank in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with the exiting code? Please clarify.

Comment: Currently i have created script static upto label 3, and i am not found able to make the script in loop using recursion or any other technique.

Comment: Please show us how you are attempting to build this JSON.

Comment: Script is long. Will u please send your email id, i will send code and MySQL file in it.